# difference between times(1) and atMostOnce() in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

what is the difference between `times(1)` and `atMostOnce()` in Mockito verify method?
as both will result in same behavior so what is the difference between them?
is their any difference in their internal working?

`verify(calculatorService, times(1)).add(10.0, 20.0);`
`verify(calculatorService, atMost(1)).add(10.0, 20.0);`

Comment: This can be answered without posting a question by 1. running the code with the most basic set of examples 2. reading the documentation `atLeastOnce` (what could *that* mean / do??)  3. just reading the english words, there are few methods with more precise names.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between `==` and `<=`:

- `times(1)` must happen exactly one time.
- `atMost(1)` can happen zero or one time.

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, it should be as follows:

- `times(1)` -> will assert that your code called mocked method exactly once
- `atMost(1)` -> asserts that your code hasn't called method more than one - note that even if you don't call method (0), the assertion should pass.